# Flutter Go Router no back button and nothing to pop

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-go-router

I am using Go Router on my flutter project and I noticed that the back button is not presented anymore.
Even when I specifically add it I get the following error:

> ======== Exception caught by gesture     ===============================================================
> The following GoError was thrown while handling a gesture:
> There is nothing to pop
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      GoRouterDelegate.pop (package:go_router/src/delegate.dart:120:5)
> #1      GoRouter.pop (package:go_router/src/router.dart:284:21)
> #2      RecordDetailState.build. (package:random_me/screens/record/detail.dart:70:36)
> #3      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1072:21)
> #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:253:24)
> #5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:627:11)
> #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:306:5)
> #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:239:7)

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppTranslations.init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(TRANSLATION.record_detail),
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              GoRouter.of(context).pop();
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
            //replace with our own icon data.
          )),
```

***Edit:*** If I call

```
GoRouter.of(context).push(CategoryDetail.routeName);
```

instead of

```
GoRouter.of(context).go(CategoryDetail.routeName);
```

it works;

Comment: The back button is not shown because Gorouter there is no page to go back to. This is also what the error message is telling you. Did you push any page? Can you show code of that?

Comment: Ok I made it work If I call the push method instead of the go method it works GoRouter.of(context).push(CategoryDetail.routeName);

Answer (score 32, accepted):

***Fixed:*** If I call

```
GoRouter.of(context).push(CategoryDetail.routeName);
```

instead of

```
GoRouter.of(context).go(CategoryDetail.routeName);
```

it works;

Comment: But the path is not showing in the address bar using this process

Answer (score 7):

It depends on how you managed your `GoRoutes` in your GoRouter configuration.

Whenever you use navigation, you have a "Navigation Stack" to manage.

Look at the two configurations below:

**Configuration 1 without sub-route**

```dart
/// The route configuration.
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const HomeScreen();
      },
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/details',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const DetailsScreen();
      },
    ),
  ],
);
```

**Configuration 2 with sub-route**

```dart
/// The route configuration.
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const HomeScreen();
      },
      routes: <RouteBase>[
        GoRoute(
          path: 'details', // Note that you don't prefix the route with '/' since it will get it from its parent route
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return const DetailsScreen();
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

First of all, you always start at the `/` route, which means that your **navigation stack** will contain the screen/page associated to the route `/`, so here `HomeScreen`.

Now, in **Configuration 1**, if you use `context.go('/details')`, since the routes `/` and `/details` are at the same level, your Navigation stack will update to replace `HomeScreen` with `DetailsScreen`.
Therefore, if you use `context.pop()` in `DetailsScreen`, you will have an error because in the Navigation stack, there is indeed nothing to pop.

In **Configuration 2**, if you also use `context.go('/details')`, since the route `/details` is a sub-route of `/`, your Navigation stack will add the screen/page associated to the route `/details` on top of the screens/pages it already has, which means that it will contain [`HomeScreen`, `DetailsScreen`].
In this case, if you use `context.pop()` in `DetailsScreen`, you will pop `DetailsScreen` and go back to `HomeScreen`.

This is the behaviour regarding the `go` method.
Now if you use the `push` method, it always adds the new screen/page on the of the Navigation stack, which means that you will always be able to use `context.pop` without worrying (unless you are at the `/` route where you won't have anything to pop).

Now it can seem better to use `push` always rather than `go` that seems to present a limitation, but the answer is: it depends on your use case, what you want to achieve.

One big limitation of the `push` method is that it doesn't work well with **Deep Linking**, whereas `go` method works great with it, but requires you to manage well how your configure your routes.

I invite you to read this [great article](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-navigation-gorouter-go-vs-push/) that explains with examples the differences between using `go` and `push` methods.

Comment: This is the right use of GoRouter. The accepted answer just solved the issue but destroyed the benefits of GoRouter.