# Flutter go_router deep link behaviour

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, flutter-go-router, flutter-deep-link

I do have initial implementation with deeplinks handling in my app with go_router

my problem:

If I already have a stack with few screens and I open deeplink it will clear my stack and open that screen only. Meaning it pops all previous screens.

Expectation - open a deeplink on top of my stack simply pushing new route.

Any ideas?

Can a deep link update just screen navigation properties - like a callback?

If I could also handle deeplinks without navigation like a global callback also would be ok.

The feature is payments - which happens on browser. And I need to navigate user back to the app on the payment screen where he was before.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your routes are well configured to have the expected behaviour you are aiming for.

I don't know which underlying navigation method deep-links use, but if it's something like `push`, it will always add the new page on top of your navigation stack, whereas if it's something like `go` from the `go_router` package, it will modify the navigation stack if the new route is not a sub-route of the old one.

You can find an example of this behaviour on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78020076/8641982).

Otherwise you have some relevant information of the topic (push vs go with some mentions of deep linking) in this [good article](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-navigation-gorouter-go-vs-push/).